# How to properly read strings from SQL Database with NumPy

Tags: python, mysql, string, numpy

I have a dataset which I am querying with SQL. My query returns a long string which simply contains the column names and then the data, with rows separated by newline characters. I then use `numpy.genfromtxt` to turn this long string into a numpy array.

However, there are a few columns that should be read as strings. So, I am explicitly passing a `dtype` array to `genfromtxt` so that it saves the column values correctly. However, when I inspect the output, all column entries that should be a string simply appear as `''`, an empty string.

I am declaring the data type of these columns as `str`. As an example, one such entry that is turning into an empty string is, in the original dataset, the word `GALAXY`. However, on the official docs for the dataset, it is listed that the data type of this column is `varchar`. I assumed `str` would be the correct type for this, but I guess not.

---

**Edit:** Ignore that this has anything to with SQL. Basically, I have a string that is the result of a query, and I need to pack it into a numpy array using `np.genfromtxt`. I avoided posting the explicit strings because they are brutal to look at, but here is one:

`b'bestObjID,ra,dec,z,zErr,zWarning,class,subClass,rChi2,DOF,rChi2Diff,z_noqso,zErr_noqso,zWarning_noqso,class_noqso,subClass_noqso,rChi2Diff_noqso,velDisp,velDispErr,velDispZ,velDispZErr,velDispChi2\n1237662340012638224,239.58334,27.233419,0.09080672,2.924875E-05,0,GALAXY,,1.104714,3735,1.411605,0,0,0,,,0,272.6187,13.61222,0,0,1815.653\n'`

As you can see, it is a `bytes` object with rows separated by `\n` and the first row being the column labels.

The result of passing this to `np.genfromtxt` is

`array((1237662340012638224, 239.58334, 27.233419, 0.09080672264099121, 2.9248749342514202e-05, 0, '', '', 1.104714035987854, 3735.0, 1.4116050004959106, 0.0, 0.0, 0, '', '', 0.0, 272.61871337890625, 13.61221981048584, 0.0, 0.0, 1815.6529541015625), 
      dtype=[('bestObjID', '<i8'), ('ra', '<f8'), ('dec', '<f8'), ('z', '<f4'), ('zErr', '<f4'), ('zWarning', '<i8'), ('class', '<c16'), ('subClass', '<c16'), ('rChi2', '<f4'), ('DOF', '<f4'), ('rChi2Diff', '<f4'), ('z_noqso', '<f4'), ('zErr_noqso', '<f4'), ('zWarning_noqso', '<i8'), ('class_noqso', '<c16'), ('subClass_noqso', '<c16'), ('rChi2Diff_noqso', '<f4'), ('velDisp', '<f4'), ('velDispErr', '<f4'), ('velDispZ', '<f4'), ('velDispZErr', '<f4'), ('velDispChi2', '<f4')])`

You can see how what should say `'GALAXY'` turns into `''` when I specify that the data type of this entry is `str`. If I instead use the `c` dataype, I can recover the `G` of `GALAXY`, but nothing more. If I try to use `c8` or `c16`, I get `(nan+0j)`

Comment: Your question sounds very mislead -- the `numpy` library is not meant to be used as a DBAPI.  If you're manipulating/reading data from a normal SQL db, can you also clarify how you ended up with trying to parse the results with `numpy`?  It sounds like that's probably where your real problem is.  Also you may want to read up on how to write an issue with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ThomasTu Well this is very specific to what I'm working on. I am querying data from the SDSS (Sloan Digital Sky Survey), using a python script provided on the SDSS website. this script does they querying, and returns a string, as I described in my first paragraph. Perhaps I should not have even mentioned SQL, my issue is really just turning a string of entries into a `numpy` array via `genfromtxt`. I'll update the post with some more info

Comment: Does [astropy/astroquery](http://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sdss/sdss.html) accomplish what you're trying to do for you?  If not, try to post an mcve and that will probably help generate a more useful answer.

Comment: @ThomasTu No, I have a custom script supplied by SDSS to do exactly what I need to do. _Everything_ is fine, except for getting this string to save in the numpy array as a string. That's all. I'm doing the querying correctly otherwise. See my edit please

Also, what's mcve?

Comment: Are you specifying a custom list of dtypes for each column?  How close does passing `dtype=None` get you to what you want?  and a mcve is a minimal complete verifiable example, which this is not, hence the downvote someone probably gave you.  I voted it up to get it to 0 because this is a legitimate question that just needs some massaging, but you should probably still post your exact `np.genfromtxt` call.

Comment: @ThomasTu You're right, this question was a bit rambly. I simplified it and made a coherent example and got a quick answer over here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838218/understanding-numpys-interpretation-of-string-data-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at how you're using genfromtxt, but this seems to work?

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

s = b'bestObjID,ra,dec,z,zErr,zWarning,class,subClass,rChi2,DOF,rChi2Diff,z_noqso,zErr_noqso,zWarning_noqso,class_noqso,subClass_noqso,rChi2Diff_noqso,velDisp,velDispErr,velDispZ,velDispZErr,velDispChi2\n1237662340012638224,239.58334,27.233419,0.09080672,2.924875E-05,0,GALAXY,,1.104714,3735,1.411605,0,0,0,,,0,272.6187,13.61222,0,0,1815.653\n'

S = lambda : StringIO(s)

np.genfromtxt(S(), dtype = None, names=True, delimiter=',')
```

outputs

```
array((1237662340012638224, 239.58334, 27.233419, 0.09080672, 2.924875e-05, 0, 'GALAXY', False, 1.104714, 3735, 1.411605, 0, 0, 0, False, False, 0, 272.6187, 13.61222, 0, 0, 1815.653), 
  dtype=[('bestObjID', '<i8'), ('ra', '<f8'), ('dec', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8'), ('zErr', '<f8'), ('zWarning', '<i8'), ('class', 'S6'), ('subClass', '?'), ('rChi2', '<f8'), ('DOF', '<i8'), ('rChi2Diff', '<f8'), ('z_noqso', '<i8'), ('zErr_noqso', '<i8'), ('zWarning_noqso', '<i8'), ('class_noqso', '?'), ('subClass_noqso', '?'), ('rChi2Diff_noqso', '<i8'), ('velDisp', '<f8'), ('velDispErr', '<f8'), ('velDispZ', '<i8'), ('velDispZErr', '<i8'), ('velDispChi2', '<f8')])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a legitimate solution, though I ended up still explicitly declaring the data types and using `a8` for the strings.