# Understanding NumPy's interpretation of string data types

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

Lets say I have a bytes object that represents some data, and I want to convert it to a `numpy` array via `np.genfromtxt`. I am having trouble understanding how I should handle strings in this case. Let's start with the following:

```
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np

text = b'test, 5, 1.2'
types = ['str', 'i4', 'f4']
np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(text), delimiter = ',', dtype = types)
```

This does not work. It raises

`TypeError: data type not understood`

If I change `types` so that `types = ['c', 'i4', 'f4']`

Then the `numpy` call returns

```
array((b't', 5, 1.2000000476837158), 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

So it works, but I am only getting the first letter of the string, obviously.

If I use `c8` or `c16` for the dtype of `test`, then I get

```
array(((nan+0j), 5, 1.2000000476837158), 
      dtype=[('f0', '<c8'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

which is garbage. I've also tried using `a`, and `U`, no success. How in the world do I get `genfromtxt` to recognize and save elements as a string?

---

**Edit:** I assume part of the ssue is that this is a `bytes` object. However, if I instead use a normal string as `text`, and use `StringIO` rather than `BytesIO`, then `genfromtxt` raises an error:

`TypeError: Can't convert`bytes`object to str implicitly`

Comment: Did you specify a length with `a`?

Comment: @user2357112 No... thank you... the solution is always too easy

Answer (score 0):

In my Python3 session:

```
In [568]: text = b'test, 5, 1.2'
# I don't need BytesIO since genfromtxt works with a list of
# byte strings, as from text.splitlines()

In [570]: np.genfromtxt([text], delimiter=',', dtype=None)
Out[570]: 
array((b'test', 5, 1.2), 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

If left to its own devices `genfromtxt` deduces that the 1st field should be `S4` - 4 bytestring characters.

I could also be explicit with the types:

```
In [571]: types=['S4', 'i4', 'f4']
In [572]: np.genfromtxt([text],delimiter=',',dtype=types)
Out[572]: 
array((b'test', 5, 1.2000000476837158), 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
In [573]: types=['S10', 'i', 'f']
In [574]: np.genfromtxt([text],delimiter=',',dtype=types)
Out[574]: 
array((b'test', 5, 1.2000000476837158), 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4')])

In [575]: types=['U10', 'int', 'float']
In [576]: np.genfromtxt([text],delimiter=',',dtype=types)
Out[576]: 
array(('test', 5, 1.2), 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

I can specify either `S` or `U` (unicode), but I also have to specify the length.  I don't think there's a way with `genfromtxt` to let it deduce the length - except for the `None` type.  I'd have to dig into the code to see how it deduces the string length.

I could also create this array with `np.array` (by making it a tuple of substrings, and giving a correct dtype:

```
In [599]: np.array(tuple(text.split(b',')), dtype=[('f0', 'S4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8')])
Out[599]: 
array((b'test', 5, 1.2), 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```